# separation of JSX file module wise

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 JSX files

1. Main.jsx

   ```
     ReactDOM.render(
    <SearchExample items={libraries} />,
    document.getElementById('container')
   ```

   );

   ReactDOM.render(
   ,
   document.getElementById('container11')
   );
2. ParentComponent.jsx

   var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
   return (

   Add a click handler to this button so that when clicked, performMagic is called in the parent component.
   Do Magic

   );
   }
   });

   var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
   performMagic: function () {
   alert('TAADAH!');
   },

   ```
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <ChildComponent onMagicClick={this.performMagic} />
            </div>
        );
    }
   ```

   });

here I am unable to call ParentComponent.
Note: I don't want to use web pack or other bundles configures.
also not want to use script tag.

Also, my main file depends on multiple files.like SearchExample.jsx, ParentComponent.jsx etc.

here may be SearchExample.jsx is also depending on some other files that contain static value/configuration/property.

I am unable to use require and import without any other library.

Comment: If you don't want to use a bundler, and you don't want to use script tags, how do you expect to get the code into your pages?

Answer (score 0):

What you want its impossible. If you dont import or put all in the same files. Maybe explain more what you want to do